# What is the way to add translation to an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, internationalization, activesupport

Sorry if this is really easy. But I have tried many ways to add I18n and does not seem to work.

This is the view

```
 =  @event.categories.map(&:name).to_sentence
```

This is in the locales

```
 #Categories
   categories:
   gastronomy: Gastronomy
   family: Family
   sports: Sports
   scene: Scene
   traditional: Tradition
   music: Music
   party: Party
```

I managed to get the translation working in the form, but not here. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Assuming have the following yaml file structure

```
categories:
  gastronomy: Gastronomy
  family: Family
  sports: Sports
  scene: Scene
  traditional: Tradition
  music: Music
  party: Party
```

Now you can do the following:

```
@event.categories.map{|n| I18n.t("categories.#{n}"}.to_sentence
```

**Option 2**

Better yet, you can alter your `Category` model to return a localized name:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  def name
    key = read_attribute(:name)
    return key if key.blank? # return immediately if nil
    # use the key as value if the localization value is missing
    I18.n("categories.#{key}", :default => key.humanize)
  end
end
```

Now, the `name` method returns a localized value:

```
cat.name # localized name
```

Your original statement will also work

```
@event.categories.map(&:name).to_sentence
```

**Option 3**

Use [Globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) gem. Watch this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/338-globalize3) for more details.

Comment: That is an awesome answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Updated the answer to handle an edge case. Take a look.